# Adding 12 hours to any time within a specific cell using cell formatting in Excel to change AM to PM

Tags: excel, time, format

**BIG EDIT**: I have been told and realize now that I cannot do this in the formatting as it is only aesthetic and not functional changes to the cell. I have since used a complex formula to change the time by default and check if the "Time in" cell is empty and it works great. Thank you to all who helped by answering and/or informed me of my incorrect assumptions

I'm creating a timesheet in Excel.

[image]

I ran into an issue where I have a habit of not putting PM into the "Time out" field and it would default to AM. So I would end up with something like 12:00 AM in the "Time in" cell and 4:00 AM in the "Time out" cell. (obviously) It wouldn't calculate the hours for that day correctly. I would rather not use a formula to increment the cell because the "Hours:" cells calculate based off of the sum of "Time in" and "time out" which would be effectively 0+12 unless the fields were filled out. So I looked into the formatting options and saw that there is no way to default to PM instead of AM (Yes, I know this is because it says 4:00 PM but is actually 16:00) so I came to the conclusion that if I could increment it in the formatting it would only apply once a value is put in.

Comment: A bit more context might be useful.

Comment: @cybernetic.nomad Added

Comment: Formating does not change the values displlayed, just how they are displayed. You are not adding context. as Rawrplus said, a few screen caps, and why this 12 hours change need to be done might help us to help you better.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to add anything. Like with many questions here, **excel already has an inbuilt functionality for this.**

Let's say we have the following times:

[image]

1. Select the area you want to change *(in this case the cells contain the time values)*
2. Right click with mouse and select the `Format Cells` option

   [image]
3. Change the format to `Custom -> h:mm AM/PM` and click OK *(duh...)*

   [image]
4. Be perplexed you didn't think of this sooner.

   [image]
5. If you want to convert all the AM times to PM, use the following formula.

> *Under presumption Column A contains the original input. Then column B will
>   be the following*

`=IF(A2<TIME(12,0,0), A2+TIME(12,0,0), A2)` this will convert all the AMs to PMs

Comment: I am aware of that format. My question is not how to get it to say AM or PM but how to default to PM instead of AM when I type something like 5:00 and hit enter or tab. I've found ways to do this aesthetically but as I mentioned in my edit it causes issues later on if I edit the "hours for the day" formula.

Comment: That's not how time works, so that's not virtually possible. Closest you can get to that is to mimic it - What I mean under that:  If you want, you can keep the input in a separate hidden column and to the column next to it do the following (under presumption the hidden one is A, and the one you are displaying is B). `=A1 & "PM"` This however is just concatenating the value from A1 with the word PM. Not a proper time format.

Comment: That is a solution I have tried and it has causes issues. That's why I asked the question if it is at all possible to add hours within the format itself.

Comment: @Excallypurr yeah, I missunderstood your original questions (that's why an example with a picture  and expected result would have been appreciated in cases like these as well).  Gimme a second, I'll edit my answer